# How to show error on focus out from input field if it is still $pristine?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a form and I need to show error on my $pristine field. if I just focus in on that field and focus out without typing anything.
But the error should not be visible from starting.

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29003/).

And here is my code...

```
<div ng-app>
  <form action="" name="myForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="n">
    <span ng-show="myForm.n.$pristine">please fill something</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="email">
    <span ng-show="">please fill something</span>
    <span ng-show="">invalid password</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="cemail">
    <span ng-show="">please fill something</span>
    <span ng-show="">password dosent match</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

I'm sorry but I have a slow internet connection and I was unable to edit the *jsfiddle*, but I made a snipped for you from your fiddle code. See code below .

Please, see the code below edited. Some aspect to take into account:

- I *fixed* some *typos* in my previous answer. My bad
- I *declared properly the app*: your code was `<div ng-app>` I replaced it for `<div ng-app="app">`
- Your controller was simple `function TodoCtrl($scope) {}`. I replaced it with the syntax `angular.module('app', []).controller('TodoCtrl', TodoCtrl);`
- The **lowest version of angular** I got this working properly was **1.2.0**

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.visible = [];
  $scope.show = function(form, input) {
    if (form && input) {
      if (form[input].$pristine && !form[input].$modelValue) {
        $scope.visible[form[input].$name] = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

angular.module('app', []).controller('TodoCtrl', TodoCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <form action="" name="myForm">
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="n" ng-blur="show(myForm, 'n')">
      <span ng-show="visible['n']">please fill something</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="email" name="myEmail" ng-blur="show(myForm, 'myEmail')">
      <span ng-show="visible['myEmail']">please fill something</span>
      <span ng-show="">invalid password</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="cemail" name="cemail" ng-blur="show(myForm, 'cemail')">
      <span ng-show="visible['cemail']">please fill something</span>
      <span ng-show="">password dosent match</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please edit the fiddle... i tried but its not working

Comment: Please see my answer edited. I wasn't able to edit the fiddle for connectivity issues. I posted a snipped from your original code. I hope it helps

Comment: What do you mean? No angular? All code in an html file? I don't get it.

Comment: no no heheh. :P .. i am saying not in angular controller... in a html file... like using $error or $invalid.....

Comment: If what you want is not to have another file containing the controller, U can move the controller code to the html file by putting it inside `<script></script>` tags on the html (if you're kind of experienced web developer, this may sound trivial to you) If what U mean is doing this without any variable manipulation on a controller, I think it's not possible. Otherwise you would need to use one of the build in variables of angular such `$error`. The drawback of this is that, then the input would be tied to some attributes, such `required`, for instance. It depends on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `required` on the Input text-box like below

```
 <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="n" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.n.$pristine || myForm.n.$error.required">please fill something</span>
  </div>
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/NaghaveerGowda/o5xwbpru/1/)

Hope this Helps!!